# Webkit text aliasing gets weird during CSS3 animations

Tags: css, webkit, css-animations

This is a funky one. And I'm sure it's webkit related since it only seems to be an issue in Chrome Version 20.0.1132.57 and Safari 5.1.7. I've uploaded a short video to explain the issue because it would be nearly impossible to explain via text.

**Video:** 
http://youtu.be/0XttO-Diz2g

**Short version:**
During CSS3 animations, text that is inside a positioned element (absolute or relative) seems to change its antialiasing. It becomes bolder while animations are running.

**Note:**
This is not the same as scaled elements becoming blurry diring an animation. ([this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417890/css3-animations-with-transform-causes-blurred-elements-on-webkit))

Any thoughts, workarounds, etc?

Comment: The relevant code is in the video, but I'll try to recreate it in jsFiddle sometime soon.

Comment: The Video link no longer works.

Comment: A jsfidle demonstrating the issue is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/UeNFK/) (courtesy of [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502234/how-to-prevent-webkit-text-rendering-change-during-css-transition)).

Comment: Unfortunately there currently doesn’t seem to be a solution except to degrade font rendering to ‘antialiased’ all the time for these elements, as the tricks in Ian’s answer below seem to do, or to make sure neither they nor any of their ancestors are relatively/absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Update: My old answer below works but is only a hacky way to resolve the issue. Instead, read this for the reason to why other elements are affected: http://jsbin.com/efirip/5/quiet. In short: an animated element should be placed in its own stacking context by giving it a `z-index`.

Old answer:

It's WebKit related. Honestly I'm not sure why it does it and I assume it's a bug too. You can prevent it by adding any 3D related CSS3 declaration to any element on the page. Example:

```
body {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Or:

```
body {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

The presence of these declarations causes WebKit to use hardware acceleration for the animations which prevents the problem you've pointed out.

Comment: WOW. That worked. How in the world did you figure that out? Well done!

Comment: This also seems to affect the initial anti-aliasing of the fonts. When I set `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;`, these seem to modify the way the font looks.

Comment: This workaround gives a small scrollbar on right when used along with twitter bootstrap.

Comment: -webkit-backface-visibility has problems with background-attachment: fixed in chrome

Comment: `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` introduces bugs in Chrome 38: http://crbug.com/422143