# ipad css transform causes a font issue

Tags: html, css, ipad-2, css-transforms

I'm doing HTML/CSS/Javascript development on iPad. I'm using css transform to translate gallery elements (li elements within an ul). The li's contain text. It all animates fine on desktop, but on iPad 2 device the animation phase makes the font somehow less bright, and when animation is completed the font returns normal. The difference is really visible, almost like going from regular font to bold and back. As said, it all is well on desktop safari, only happens on iPad mobile safari.

Anyone having the same issue?

.pom.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this and other slightly odd behaviour which is down to hardware acceleration for 3d transforms but I haven't found a single standard 'fix'.  In order to try better to understand the problem, take a look at tips here:

http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d

and here:-

[How to force re-render after a WebKit 3D transform in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641522/how-to-force-re-render-after-a-webkit-3d-transform-in-safari)