# Preventing blurry rendering with transform: scale

Tags: html, css

I'm scaling a `div` up with the transform property, but I want to keep its children (which have `1px` width or height) the same size. I counter-scaled them by `.5`, with the expected result that an element of `1px` scaled by 2, and then .5, should end up back at `1px`, but they wind up a blurry `2px`.

Here's the box before scaling it:

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    position: absolute;
}

.outline {
    position: absolute;
    background: #1899ef;
    z-index: 999999;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.outlineBottom, .outlineTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.outlineLeft, .outlineRight {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}

.outlineRight {
    right: 0px;
}

.outlineBottom {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="outline outlineTop"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineRight"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineBottom"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineLeft"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the elements at the edges are a clear, dark `1px` blue. Here's what the box looks like *after* scaling, though:

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(2);
}

.outline {
    position: absolute;
    background: #1899ef;
    z-index: 999999;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transform: scale(.5);
}

.outlineBottom, .outlineTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  transform: scale(1,.5);
}

.outlineLeft, .outlineRight {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    transform: scale(.5,1);
}

.outlineRight {
    right: 0px;
}

.outlineBottom {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="outline outlineTop"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineRight"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineBottom"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineLeft"></div>
</div>
```

[And here's a post-scaled render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl1Up.png) from Chrome 41.0.2272.89 Mac, which is what I'm running.

[Adding `transform-3d(0, 0, 0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001681/css-transform-scale-makes-text-blurry) didn't appear to help. A [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/cLL6e16u/2/) was found using the [`zoom` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome), but since `zoom` isn't well supported I'd like to avoid that. Adding `filter: blur(0px);` didn't appear to have any effect either.

It was [posited in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22057025#22057025) that perhaps the children are first scaled to `.5` and then doubled in size, causing them to be scaled down to `.5px` and then back up from there. Is there any way to ensure the order that they're rendered in causes them to first be scaled up to `2px` and then halved? Against my better judgement, I tried [forcing the render order with JS](http://jsfiddle.net/cLL6e16u/1/), but unsurprisingly, that didn't have any effect (though, interestingly, the bottom element did maintain its original color).

Failing that, are there any other solutions floating around out there? I can't be the only one who's run into this problem.

Comment: Any chance you can show a before / after? It is unclear what the issue is

Comment: Before / after scaling? Not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, before and after the scaling. I don't really see any issue with the box that you currently have - but that's probably because I am unclear of the desired effect

Comment: @Adjit Hopefully that should clear things up for you.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution finally, and it was so close (and yet so far :P) from the tests yesterday

Comment: Thanks, @AlvaroMontoro, I appreciate the help yesterday, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is to do with the default `transform-origin` on the scaled elements.  It defaults to `50% 50%` for any element being transformed, but this has issues when scaling down 1px values as it has to centre the `scale` on a half pixel and the rendering of the elements has issues from here on out.  You can see it working here with the `transform-origin` moved to the relevant extremes for each item.

A bit of playing about shows that this same blurring happens on scaled elements for any dimension where the scaling ends up halving a pixel.

```css
body {
    padding: 1em;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(2);
}

.outline {
    position: absolute;
    background: #1899ef;
    z-index: 999999;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.outlineBottom, .outlineTop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    transform: scale(1, 0.5);
}

.outlineBottom {
    bottom: 0;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.outlineTop {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.outlineLeft, .outlineRight {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    transform: scale(.5,1);
}

.outlineRight {
    right: 0px;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.outlineLeft {
    left: 0px;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="outline outlineTop"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineRight"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineBottom"></div>
    <div class="outline outlineLeft"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No worries, I'd never seen this issue before but with a bit of playing it sort of makes sense that this would happen ... a feature rather than a bug I think, as you wouldn't want transform origins to be guessed in these sort of situations!

Comment: This is a really clean solution. And so simple :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what the actual solution is? I see that you're setting `transform-origin` to different values, depending on the element, but I don't quite understand the idea behind it.