# Css skew + any other 3D transform component causes major Blurriness content

Tags: css

I am creating a site that where each section is a trapezoid. I used css skew and stack each on top of one another and it is working seamlessly.  The one issue I am having is when ever I add an element to the page that uses css 3D transform all content inside section gets blurred. (slick slider,  canvas charts. etc... )

Here is a crude example:
https://codepen.io/MMDragon3/pen/ZJpdXM

```
-webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this too. Sadly I don't think there is. Like they say here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641522/how-to-force-re-render-after-a-webkit-3d-transform-in-safari/4847445#4847445 I don't know if this behavior is standard. If it is that's bad.